# Type hinting an enum property that returns an instance of that enum

Tags: python-3.x, enums, type-hinting

I have an enum that looks like this:

```
class Direction(Enum):
    NORTH = 0
    EAST = 1
    SOUTH = 2
    WEST = 3

    @property
    def left(self) -> Direction:
        new_direction = (self.value - 1) % 4
        return Direction(new_direction)

    @property
    def right(self) -> Direction:
        new_direction = (self.value + 1) % 4
        return Direction(new_direction)
```

I am trying to type hint the `left` and `right` properties to indicate their return value is of type `Direction`.

I thought the above would work, but when I run the code I get the following error: `NameError: name 'Direction' is not defined`. I guess this is happening because the Python interpreter does not yet know what the `Direction` enum is at the time of defining this function.

My question is, is there anyway I can type hint these properties? Thanks.

Comment: Python 3.8 allows forward references if you `from __future__ import annotations` otherwise just quote the type, e.g. `'Direction'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a forward reference as the Direction class isn't defined yet when the property function signature is executed. You'll need to put the forward reference in quotes. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references for more information.

```
from enum import Enum

class Direction(Enum):
    NORTH = 0
    EAST = 1
    SOUTH = 2
    WEST = 3

    @property
    def left(self) -> 'Direction':
        new_direction = (self.value - 1) % 4
        return Direction(new_direction)

    @property
    def right(self) -> 'Direction':
        new_direction = (self.value + 1) % 4
        return Direction(new_direction)
```

Comment: In Py3.8 you can use `from __future__ import annotations`, then these forward declarations do not need to be quoted.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the information I needed! @AChampion I am using Python 3.8 so I will take advantage of `annotations`. Appreciate the useful advice.